# Getting The State History of an Order

Tags: orders, ce-1.6.2.0

Is it possible to get the order **state** history of an order? I'm able to get the statuses using sales/order_status_history model.

```
$orderHistory = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $order->getId());
```

This only brings back the order status and comment (and a few other bits).

Is there any way I can get the state the order was in for each status? I can't see it stored anywhere other than in the order table but that's the current state.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the order status thru the history collection you define, to get the state of a status you can use:

```
 $statusCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_collection')
 ->joinStates();
```

In this collection you can lookup the status and check the assigned state.

Comment: Thanks. I take it this is just getting the current state and status links? So it wouldn't get what it was at the time of the order? It should be fine as I don't think it has changed.